# Is it possible to convert a ruby array or hash into a cucumber data table

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a very peculiar requirement.
My cucumber statement is

```
    * I activate only the reference tables but not rows of the customer 'Pepsi'
      | Table Name |
      | CUSTCFG1   |
      | MARGINTRF  |
```

I have a second statement

```
   * I activate all reference tables of the customer
      | Customer Name | Customer JSON File|                                                                |
      | Netwealth     | customerdata.json |
```

And from the customer json I work out an array of table names

```
table_names  = ["CUSTCFG1","MARGINTRF"]
```

I want to reuse the first cucumber statement inside the above cucumber statement. Something like this

```
Given(/^I activate all reference tables of the customer$/) do |customer_details|
  customer_details.hashes.each {|customer_detail|
    customer_data = JSON.parse(File.read(Dir.pwd + "/#{customer_detail['Customer JSON File']}"))
    table_names = JsonPath.on(customer_data, '$.ReferenceTables..Name')
    step "I activate only the reference tables but not rows of the customer '#{customer_detail['Customer Name']}'", table_names
```

This fails because "table_names" is not a cucumber table.

Is there a way I can resolve this roadblock

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `terminal-table`.

1. Install the gem [terminal-table](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table)

   ```
   gem install terminal-table
   ```
2. Write your Ruby code similar to

   ```
   require 'terminal-table'

   array = [
     ['Customer Name', 'Customer JSON File'],
     ['Netwealth', 'customerdata.json']
   ]

   table = Terminal::Table.new do |t|
     t.style = { :border_top => false, :border_bottom => false }
     array.each { |row|  t << row }
   end

   puts table
   ```
3. Output as cucumber table:

   ```
   | Customer Name | Customer JSON File |
   | Netwealth     | customerdata.json  |
   ```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a quick workaround, here is my current solution - assuming you have your test data already in a hash.

```rb
hash = { 'header1': 'value1', 'header2': 'value2' }

Cucumber::MultiLineArgument::DataTable.from([hash.keys, hash.values])
```

Done while using `cucumber 8.0.0`